# Composer psr-4 autoload issue

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload, psr-4

I have problem with autoloading with composer when i use psr-4 autoloading it doesn't work and give me error.

I tried:

```
$ composer dump-autoload
```

and a lot of other thing but it doesn't work without

```
require one;
```

error:

```
You are now a master builder, that knows how to autoload with a 
classmap! 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'VegithemesLibraryGreeting' not 
found in /home/vaclav/Server/vssk/VSSK/project/aldemo/index.php:10 
Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in 
/home/vaclav/Server/vssk/VSSK/project/aldemo/index.php on line 10
```

composer.json:

```
{
"autoload": {
    "files": ["mylibrary/functions.php"],

    "classmap": [
    "classmap"
    ],

    "psr-4": {
        "one\\": "src/"
    }
  }
}
```

greeting.php (file with class to load):

```
<?php
namespace one;

Class Greeting
{
    public function hi()
    {
        return "We got you covered";
    }
}
```

index.php file:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

echo lego();

$cm = new Cmautoload;
echo $cm->classmap();

$vt = new oneGreeting;

echo $vt->hi();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is generally good practice to capitalize the first letter of a class name. It also adheres with the rules of [PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/).

Change your composer.json file to look like this:

```
{
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "mylibrary/functions.php"
    ],

    "classmap": [
        "classmap"
    ],

    "psr-4": {
        "One\\": "src/"
    }
  }
}
```

Now, in your index file. We are going to import the autoloader. To do this simply require it:

`require 'vendor/autoload.php';`

Now that you have included the autoloader, go into every class and set the namespace.

The classes in your `src/` == `namespace One;`

Check your classes in `src/` and make sure they are all namespaced. Meaning that they should all have the following line of code at the top:

`namespace One;`

As mentioned before, update your file names to `Foo.php` and class names to
`class Foo` to adhere to PSR. (This is not required but highly recommended and standard procedure.)

To use one of your classes you would say `use One\Greeting;`

```
$greeting = new Greeting();
echo $greeting->hi(); //"We got you covered"
```

Comment: I did everything and still the same.

Answer (score 5):

I found the problem, there was missing:

```
use One\Greeting;
```

In a lot of tutorials there isn't a word about it.

Comment: I did mention that in my last line. But I am glad you found it!

Answer (score 5):

Another relevant detail about this is the namespace must match with the folder structure.
If not it will throw the warning.

Comment: This also includes case-sensetive folder naming. I've searched 2 days for the bug to get it fixed. Holy crap. And funny enough it was caused by a typo.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the filename was

```
src/One/GreetingClass.php
```

but the class name was in lowercase, causing this error:

```
class Greetingclass {
```

Changing the class declaration as GreetingClass fixed the issue.